# Can I set a base URL for all OAuth2Session requests?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, requests-oauthlib

My question is specifically regarding the Microsoft Graph API, but a more widely applicable solution would be welcome.

I have a session instantiated as follows:

```
# Token acquisition code left out
session = OAuth2Session(token=token)
```

HTTP requests with this session look like this:

```
# List files in OneDrive
response = session.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children")
```

Is it possible to set a base URL so I can leave out the `base_url` each time? I would like to be able to make the call like this:

```
# List files in OneDrive
response = session.get("me/drive/root/children")
```

I was able to do this by subclassing `OAuth2Session` and overloading the `Session.request()` method, but this strikes me as the wrong approach.

```
# Bad hack
class GraphSession (OAuth2Session):
    def request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > 1: # url as non-kw arg
            args = list(args) # can't assign to a tuple
            args[1] = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/' + args[1]
        else: # url must be a kw arg
            kwargs['url'] = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/' + kwargs['url']
        return super(GraphSession, self).request(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why not just use a function to append them for you, and return the response/session object?

Comment: @Xosrov Yeah, I could do that. I figured this would be a common enough use-case that there would be a built-in way to do it that I was just missing, but maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app/blob/644ceb36c889f402d50dadf2f08d334f683ddd55/helpers.py#L16) from [Python console application for Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app#python-console-application-for-microsoft-graph) sample.

```py
def api_endpoint(url):
    """Convert a relative path such as /me/photo/$value to a full URI based
    on the current RESOURCE and API_VERSION settings in config.py.
    """
    if urllib.parse.urlparse(url).scheme in ['http', 'https']:
        return url # url is already complete
    return urllib.parse.urljoin(f'{config.RESOURCE}/{config.API_VERSION}/',
                                url.lstrip('/'))
```